# how can I covert this to a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

My test.txt file includes:

```
2 2 4
1 1 3 
4 1 1 
1 1 1 
4 1 2
2 2 1
3 2 3
2 1 1
```

My Python code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import 
import os
A=np.loadtxt("C:\Users\KEMAL\Desktop\piton\test.txt")
n=3 
for i in range(0,n):
    b=[row[i] for row in A]
    D=np.array(b)
    size=[len(D),np.max(D)]
    B=np.zeros(size)
    for i in range(len(D)):
        idx=D[i]-1
        B[i,idx]=1
        U=B.transpose(1, 0)

    print U
```

And via this code written as above and this codes give me this:

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]
[[ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]]
[[ 0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

This is not a matrix!  I want to convert the matrix as below and I've failed  every attempt.

```
[[ 0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Excuse me my title ask is  'How can I convert this to a matrix...

Comment: `A` from `loadtxt` should be a 2d array (lets skip the `matrix` name).  Describe in words what you are trying to acomplish.  What is `U` supposed to be?  Looks like you are printing 4 instances of `U`, each a 2d array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest replacing your for-loop with something like the following:

```
A = np.loadtxt("C:\Users\KEMAL\Desktop\piton\test.txt").T

s = A.max(axis=1).cumsum()
data = np.zeros((int(s[-1]), A.shape[1]))

A[1:] += s[:2, None]
i = (A - 1).astype(int)
j = np.tile(np.arange(A.shape[1]), (A.shape[0], 1))

data[i, j] = 1
```

So that `>>> data` gives:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

This should be faster. If you want to keep with your slower for-loop solution, you should `vstack` the resulting arrays:

```
A=np.loadtxt("C:\Users\KEMAL\Desktop\piton\test.txt")
n=3
arrs = []
for i in range(0,n):
    b=[row[i] for row in A]
    D=np.array(b)
    size=[len(D),np.max(D)]
    B=np.zeros(size)
    for i in range(len(D)):
        idx=D[i]-1
        B[i,idx]=1
        U=B.transpose(1, 0)

    arrs.append(U)

np.vstack(arrs)
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
NewU=list()
for i in U:
    NewU+=i
print NewU
```

I'm not familiar with numpy so I'm not sure it'll work, but it's worth giving a try.